# Cannot change tab label in MobaXterm

Tags: bash, rename, mobaxterm, label, ps1

I am using MobaXterm v20.6 and WSL2+Ubuntu 20.04 from Microsoft Store. I am trying to label the tabs defining PS1 like: PS1="\e]0;\u@\h\a\w #" but tabs are still labeled as "1. WSL-Ubuntu"

From the same terminal, if I launch xterm, this PS1 correctly labels the window title as USER@HOST. If I open a local terminal (Cygwin), this PS1 correctly labels the window title as USER@HOST. The problem is seen with only WSL-Ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue until I realized I had 'Lock terminal title' ticked in the Bookmark settings

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks.